# wordpress url rewrite $_ get variables with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

ive seen a few questions like this floating about, but they are slightly different to my needs so im going to outline it here as i am banging my head against the wall on this one...

i have permalinks set up using WordPress's permalink structure %category%/%postname%/, and have build some custom wordpress template files that use _GET variables in the url so myurl.com/region-home/?ssf_p_id=7 uses the ssf_p_id variable to do stuff, and in this case the region-home page has an id of 56

what i am trying to achieve is to replace the variable with some text myurl.com/region-home/kenboody

what i was thinking of doing was some kind of re-write rule that is specific to that variable, there are only 9 or so instances of this variable so what i would like to do is something like this:

```
if ?ssf_p_id=1 - url will read /region-home/something
if ?ssf_p_id=2 - url will read /region-home/different
if ?ssf_p_id=3 - url will read /region-home/each-time
```

and so on

i have tired adding some RewriteRule followed by a regular expression from some google searches that i have been making, the problem is i have no idea how the regular expressions work, so im probably missing some kind of slash in the wrong place

this is as far as i have gotten with it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^region-home/something$ index.php?post_id=56&ssf_p_id=1
RewriteRule ^region-home/different$ index.php?post_id=56&ssf_p_id=2
RewriteRule ^region-home/each-time$ index.php?post_id=56&ssf_p_id=3    
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

this code has no effect on the url at all, but it does break the css, im getting a 404 for the css doc in the header of the page, that is all the effects i can see happening

any help on this would be much appreciated

thanks

TB

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use php to get the request uri and look for the last part of your url.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/something') !== false) {
    $ssf_p_id = 1; // obviously you wouldn't need to set this variable, just do what you need to do if it was set in the request.
}
```

Comment: using that method will require me to build mulitple separate template pages, in this case i only need one page, that gets stuff from the database depending on the variable, im looking to extend this in the future with more instances maybe up to 30 or more, so would like to try and use the url rewrite if possible and keep using one template file

Comment: Frankly, that doesn't make much sense to me.  Using url rewriting, you will effectively need a different rule for not only each page, but each ssf_p_id key you decide you want to use.  How is running the parsing code once, possibly in your DB connection file, and setting a global variable you can look at later worse?

Comment: i ended up choosing a different route and using custom fields in individual pages, this was a better solution than the first thought, thanks for your help anyway